# Master sound management windows 10

Tags: c, winapi, audio

I need to change master volume in Windows 10, but I can only change the volume of my application. Someone know how do that in C ?

Maybe use windows API ?

Comment: See [Endpoint Volume Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370839(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I have a problem with #include <mmdeviceapi.h> "No such file or directory" but I download it, put in MinGW/include but it's the same, and #include <endpointvolume.h> too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Windows Vista we have:

1. Stream Volume
2. Simple Volume
3. Channel Volume
4. Endpoint Volume

You need to change the [endpoint volume](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). So you need the [IAudioEndpointVolume](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) interface.

The steps in the code that follows is to get an `IMMDeviceEnumerator`. With the enumerator you get the default audio endooint with `GetDefaultAudioEndpoint`. In the `IAudioEndpointVolume` interface you find `Get/SetMasterVolumeLevel`

The following sample code is taken from [Larry Osterman's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2007/03/06/how-do-i-change-the-master-volume-in-windows-vista/). Be aware that there is no error checking.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <endpointvolume.h>

void Usage()
{
  printf("Usage: \n");
  printf(" SetVolume [Reports the current volume]\n");
  printf(" SetVolume -d <new volume in decibels> [Sets the current default render device volume to the new volume]\n");
  printf(" SetVolume -f <new volume as an amplitude scalar> [Sets the current default render device volume to the new volume]\n");

}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  HRESULT hr;
  bool decibels = false;
  bool scalar = false;
  double newVolume;
  if (argc != 3 && argc != 1)
  {
    Usage();
    return -1;
  }
  if (argc == 3)
  {
    if (argv[1][0] == '-')
    {
      if (argv[1][1] == 'f')
      { 
        scalar = true;
      }
      else if (argv[1][1] == 'd')
      {
        decibels = true;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      Usage();
      return -1;
    }

    newVolume = _tstof(argv[2]);
  }

  // -------------------------
  CoInitialize(NULL);
  IMMDeviceEnumerator *deviceEnumerator = NULL;
  hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (LPVOID *)&deviceEnumerator);
  IMMDevice *defaultDevice = NULL;

  hr = deviceEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eConsole, &defaultDevice);
  deviceEnumerator->Release();
  deviceEnumerator = NULL;

  IAudioEndpointVolume *endpointVolume = NULL;
  hr = defaultDevice->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioEndpointVolume), CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, NULL, (LPVOID *)&endpointVolume);
  defaultDevice->Release();
  defaultDevice = NULL; 

  // -------------------------
  float currentVolume = 0;
  endpointVolume->GetMasterVolumeLevel(&currentVolume);
  printf("Current volume in dB is: %f\n", currentVolume);

  hr = endpointVolume->GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(&currentVolume);
  printf("Current volume as a scalar is: %f\n", currentVolume);
  if (decibels)
  {
    hr = endpointVolume->SetMasterVolumeLevel((float)newVolume, NULL);
  }
  else if (scalar)
  {
    hr = endpointVolume->SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar((float)newVolume, NULL);
  }
  endpointVolume->Release();

  CoUninitialize();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I have a problem : `unknown type name '_TCHAR'; did you mean 'PTCHAR'?`

Comment: Just `#include <tchar.h>`. Changed answer.

Comment: It's good ! Now I have many errors like : `expected expression before MMDeviceEnumerator` or `'IMMDeviceEnumerator {aka struct IMMDeviceEnumerator}' has no member named 'GetDefaultAudioEndpoint'|` or `'IMMDevice {aka struct IMMDevice}' has no member named 'Activate'|`

Comment: I can't repro your problems. I just can compile the sample without warnings or errors. What SDK are you using, what VS-version? And even if you have problems with some headers, you have your answer. Any other problems have nothing to do with your initial question.

Comment: I use Code::Blocks with MinGW 64, I know, thanks for your answers.

Comment: Mark the question as answered, if it is an answer. I write this because you are new to stackoverflow.com

Comment: It may be the right answer but it does not work for me. Windows exemples are in C++ then I'm learning it now.

Comment: If you need to use C, only you must call COM in a C-way. This is quite compilcated. And even C is a subset of C++, it doesn't makle sense to learn it alone! Remember a bunch of WinAPI functions use COM!

Comment: I'm in formation and I start a 5 months stage. I have to choose which language to use for the management of an audio module (windows api and libvlc), and I didn't know what to do

Comment: Than I can tell you that C is a bad choice!

Comment: What do you advise ?